# How to use MySQL database connection pooling across multiple Python modules

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am new to Flask trying to implement MySQL connection pooling **without** using SQLAlchemy. I did some research and found out how to define a connection pool using mysql-connector-python (8.0.27). The following [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html) from the official MySQL website provides an example.

```
dbconfig = {
  "database": "test",
  "user":     "joe"
}

cnxpool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "mypool",
                                                      pool_size = 3,
                                                      **dbconfig)
cnx1 = cnxpool.get_connection()
cnx2 = cnxpool.get_connection()
```

The code appears pretty straight-forward and tests fine fine when used in a simple Python file. But if I want to use the same connection pool across multiple Python modules, how and **where** do I define the connection pool so that it can be reused? My app uses a Flask factory function to initialize. Can someone please assist?

At present, my Flask application uses the following database model (Flask Tutorial 2.0):

**db.py**

```
import mysql.connector
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

# Function to create a database connection.
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db=mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="dbuser",password="test123",database="testdb")
    return g.db

# Function to close an existing database connection.
def close_db(e=None):
    db=g.pop('db',None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

# Function to initialize the database from a script.
def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    # current_app is necessary to specify the location of the file relative to the application directory.
    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        scriptline=f.readline()
        # Checks for end of script file.
        # Ensure that schema.sql stores each command in a single line.
        while scriptline:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(scriptline)
            cursor.close()
            scriptline=f.readline()
    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    # Delete existing data and re-create tables.
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the test database.')

# Register with the application.
def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

I can figure out that I have to modify my get_db() function as follows:

```
# Function to create a database connection.
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db=cnxpool.get_connection()
    return g.db
```

My question is: Where and how do I define the connection pool itself as the get_db() procedure may be called from different Python modules or Flask blueprints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. The solution is to create a singleton class to define the connection pool and then instantiate it only once inside the factory function. Once the connection pool is initialised, we can store it in the `app.config` dictionary object so that it is accessible by other modules throughout the lifespan of the application. We may need to use the `current_app` reference while creating a connection from the pool.